# It the positioning question a duplicate of the safety question

Tags: discussion

Simple meta question really...

There is my question about positioning:

[Body positioning while using a jointer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/body-positioning-while-using-a-jointer)

Then there is a general jointer safety question:

[What safety precautions should I take when using a jointer?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/what-safety-precautions-should-i-take-when-using-a-jointer)

Is the first question now a duplicate of the second? My hunch says yes but my question is very specific as are the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh; I hate when this happens. As it stands, I agree your question is now in danger of being marked as a duplicate of the newer question.  I think once the dust has settled and everyone has had their say in the more general question, you could salvage your question by limiting the scope a little more--for example, reference the newer question, clarify that you know you should use a push pad, and focus more on the part of your question that asked whether or not you should walk alongside the board as it passes across the jointer.

Comment: You would say that the dust has settled now then?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. There are enough answers on the other question that people have started posting general power tool safety tips, and at a glance it looks like none of them address body position.